# verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate (openssl)

Tags: https, openssl

I have secured a webserver behind https using a CA that does not comes with my OS (ubuntu). I therefore need to specify that CA when I want to connect to the server I have tried to test the connection with:

```
$ openssl s_client -CApath /home/user/my-certs/ -connect myhost.internal:443
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
....
verify return:1
140085612160320:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1543:SSL alert number 40
```

I also verified that the certificate in the path is `OK`:

```
$ openssl verify /home/user/my-certs/myhost.internal.cer
/home/user/my-certs/myhost.internal.cer: OK
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I proceed with debugging the problem?

Comment: To use `-CApath` correctly, the cert files or links in that directory must have names which are the 8-hex-char truncated hash of the subject followed by dot and _usually_ zero -- `internal-ca.cer` is definitely NOT such a name. See the man page for verify on your system [or on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/verify.html), as referenced from the man page for s_client, and more details on referenced man page for c_rehash. In addition you are apparently verifying that CA against the default truststore, but not using the default in s_client.  ...

Comment: ...   However, `s_client` ignores any cert validation error and continues; the actual _error_ here is that the server rejected your connection, and that's not because of your cert settings. The best approach is to check server logs to see what it doesn't like; if you can't do that, turn on `-state` and maybe `-msg` to examine where in the protocol this occurs and what the client is sending, and try to guess based on your knowledge of the server and detailed understanding of the TLS protocols what in that protocol the server doesn't like.